# Xcode 10 - Launch storyboard with static images

Tags: ios, xcode, launchimage

Currently I'm using static launch images to be able to show a full-screen image on app startup,  which can show a different image: one designed for portrait and one for landscape. The only way I've been able to do this is to NOT use storyboards.

However, I want my app to run on a new iPad Pro with no letterboxing, so it looks like I'll have to use a launch storyboard.  But I'm afraid I won't be able to implement the adaptive launch images I have set up....

So it is possible, even practical, to use full-screen, orientation-dependent images within a launch storyboard?

Comment: Any updates on this? there is a huge difference in iPad 2 and new iPad pro resolutions, what should be the ideal size of the 1x,2x, 3x, to support all different iPads without drastic scaling or resizing?